# powershell in bat file and with parameters

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I can't run my powershell with a parameter input within a batch file. Any idea?

Sample command. All are failing:

1. `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe .\Migrate.ps1 '\\\server\Shared\MSK Directory' '\\\server1\Shared\MSK Directory'`
2. `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe .\Migrate.ps1 "\\\server\Shared\MSK Directory" "\\\server1\Shared\MSK Directory"`
3. `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe .\Migrate.ps1 &"\\\server\Shared\MSK Directory" &"\\\server1\Shared\MSK Directory"`

Comment: Is .\Migrate in the same folder you're executing the batch file from? You may need to alter your batch file to set the location to whatever folder your file is in.

Comment: Any error message(s)?

Comment: Why not run the script directly from a PowerShell window?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, but your UNC path is wrong. UNC path only needs two backslashes. You should also make sure that you are in the same folder as the script, if not, use full paths. Also, I would recommend using the `-File` parameter when calling a script file.

```
powershell.exe -File .\Migrate.ps1 '\\server\Shared\MSK Directory' '\\server1\Shared\MSK Directory'
```

Demo:

Untitled3.ps1

```
param($to, $from)

Write-Host "To: '$to'"
Write-Host "From: '$from'"
```

Output:

```
powershell .\Untitled3.ps1 '\\server\Shared\MSK Directory' '\\server1\Shared\MSK Directory'

To: '\\server\Shared\MSK Directory'
From: '\\server1\Shared\MSK Directory'
```

Using `-File`

```
powershell -File .\Untitled3.ps1 "\\server\Shared\MSK Directory" "\\server1\Shared\MSK Directory"

To: '\\server\Shared\MSK Directory'
From: '\\server1\Shared\MSK Directory'
```